# Does Stack Overflow use Data Analytics to understand users' behaviour?

Tags: discussion

Based on my previous experience I have got a hint that Stack Overflow uses some complex techniques to understand users' behaviour which is almost real time.

Thus, I would like to know if Stack Overflow uses data analytics or moderations to understand users' behaviour (like fraud voting) or predict the same.

I had a question on this as in case: If it does, why won't it use it to its full extent to handle the new users? If the same is being used (I'm not aware of it at this moment) we can decrease number of duplicates and doesn't require moderation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we monitor a lot of things that users do and use that information to inform the decisions we make regarding new or existing features. We also monitor voting and automatically invalidate votes... although there's still cases where we have to manually investigate more elaborate patterns.

So, full automation isn't always possible, since there's a high number of false positives in some situations. Analyzing new users' posts in particular is difficult due to natural language parsing being unreliable/uninterpretable in some cases. And we tend to err a bit on the side of caution when it comes to votes.

All in all, the answer to you question is "yes, we look at data" and "no, it's not feasible to create fully automated handling of negative behaviours".

That isn't to say that there's no possible improvement we *could* make at all... so if you have a specific suggestion of how we could reliably identify question duplicates (or any other issues), please post feature requests for those. You can likely use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) to test your proposals (except for vote analysis) before bringing them forward as well.